# Insert 1 instance to another

Tags: c#

Kinda of a stupid question, but it confuses me.

Is there a difference between:

```
Dictionary<short, String> details= new <short, String>()
Dictionary<short, String> tmpDetails = db.getDetails();

foreach (var tmpDetails in tmpDetails )
{
     details.Add(tmpDetails.Key, tmpDetails.Value);
}
```

and:

```
Dictionary<short, String> details= new <short, String>()
Dictionary<short, String> tmpDetails = db.getDetails();

details = tmpDetails;
```

If i insert 1 instance to another?

Comment: I don't think that code compiles. The Dictionary declaration after the new keyword is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example you are *copying* the items from one `Dictionary` to another; they are separate instances.  If you add values to one instance, the other is unaffected.

In your second example, you are *referencing* the same instance with both variables.  If you add values through one reference, the other reference sees the additional values.

Think of them as boxes - in the first case, you have two boxes, and are *copying* the items from one box to another.

In the second example, they are *the same box* - both references see the same items inside, and both are affected if anything is added/removed/modified.